# Gumble of thread through bobbin hole? Thread loose on down-side of cloth?

Tags: sewing, sewing-machine

1. I've had an issue where after I set my presser-foot lifter and begin
   to sew in a straight-line thread pattern.
2. The needle does stall due to
   insufficient torque.
3. Then, I release the foot and raise the cloth
   off the feed plate.
4. The threads are not tightened up to the cloth;
   rather, they are loose, frayed, and gumming-up the feed-dog hole.
   [image: an image of a sewing machine shows the presser foot pushing the cloth onto the feed platform and the feed dog hole through which the bobbin thread exits into the seen-cloth.]

So, I pull out the
cloth, cut all the loose bends, check that everything is set
according to the manual, and repeat the process only to run into the
same bug....

Here's an image of the aftermath....
[image: an image of the loose cloth coming out of the back of the sewn-cloth.]

So, somehow the thread taken into the back of the shirt is not entering tightly but it's rather being kept under the feed-dog hole until I lift the sewn-cloth and manually pull the gumbled-thread out of the feed-dog hole.

I'll send a photo of my rig and the gummed up feed-dog hole after 48 hours. Until that time, please let me know if there would be other useful info.

Comment: Hi Wolfpack, I don't really understand why you didn't wait with asking this question once you got all the pictures (especially since there are some here already), but I can imagine this question is clear enough to be provided with answers from users more familiar with sewing.

Comment: That makes sense, and, like I said, I can see how this question is clear enough. I'm not sure about your third point, though: what do you mean by it, exactly?

Comment: I mean clout traders get into se and harass new members with arbitrary rules because it is an easy way to pick up a few dozen credit from meta contributors who are really only hear to abuse people with vitriol-laced insults. It's better to not post perfect questions because it exposes them. Eventually, the site owners will smarten up and create controls to prevent users like that having advanced admin tools or increase the level of adherence to reasonable values for a semi-public forum.

Comment: The "rules" are not arbitrary, StackExchange makes its clear that people should do their homework before posting a question. Not threading the machine correctly is pretty basic; a little effort would have saved some grief. Same goes about searching the site for similar questions before posting. This [one from 2016](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/1839/416) has the answer you posted to your own question within a day in its first comment and in top answer.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this one: [How can I stop my thread from bunching when using a sewing machine?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/1839/416) or possibly, if your bobbin is damaged, this one: [Sewing machine problem: machine won't tighten the loops under the material](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/q/5307/416)

Answer (score 0):

[image: a photo of a thread properly wrapped around the thread-guide.]
This bug is reliable reproduced by not properly wrapping the thread under the thread-guide (at the red u-turn indicator). The lack of sufficient pully-caused tension results in the top thread expanding into the feed-dog chamber rather than being pulled tautly against the underside of the sewn-cloth.

Other signs of this operator-caused error are a loose top-thread or an overactive spool, but the easiest way to verify the problem is to follow the thread. The thread should be fully behind the thread-guide-ridge, leaving it inexposed.

Additionally, looser thread types should go into the **duck-eye**--see image, red circle--(between the spool and thread-guide) rather than beneath the **duck**--see image, purple square--, resulting in greater tension on the line.
[image: image of duck-eye, red circle; duck, purple square.]

Comment: And is this an actual answer, or an addition to your question? If the latter, you can edit your question to add this information.

Comment: I missed this because the thread crosses the thread-guide over a very short distance, making it fiddlingly difficult to see without more careful inspection.

Comment: Ah, okay - that's all I needed to know :) And no problem, of course!

Comment: And what does "Go op the ops. Meta ops are the worst people on Earth." mean? What are "ops" and "meta ops"?